# Index and Table size issue

Tags: postgresql, postgresql-9.5

My table size is 2.5 TB, it includes 10 indexes. The data size is 850 GB and index size is 1650 GB. To reduce the size of indexes I have to rebuild the indexes.My maintenance window duration is 5 hours. I think it's difficult (or not possible) to complete index rebuild operation for this table within MW. Please suggest which approach is the fastest way to reduce the indexes size in 5 hrs MW?

create new table with original table structure without indexes and start data copy from original table to new table. Then rename the table and create indexes. will this approach work for me? Please suggest.

My PGSQL version: 9.5

Comment: With a modern Postgres version you could use `reindex concurrently`

Comment: 10 indexes is suspect. Is your schema normalised upto 3NF?

Comment: No one can tell you how long it will take your hardware to build an index on your data.  That is what test servers are for.